# Getting a 'Use of unassigned local variable'in list pattern with variable with .NET 7

Tags: c#, .net-7.0, linqpad7

I have tested out list patterns in .NET 7 and C#. I am using Linqpad 7 and .NET 7.0.1.
List patterns are useful I guess to compared sequences and fun to test out. The '_' discard here means to ignore the number at a given position and the '..' range here is to match anything between a given set of value and one index and then a given value at a higher index with arbitrary values between.

But in one of the samples, it says you can capture variables inside list patterns. I cannot make it work, I get a compiler error.

I am getting a CS0165 'Use of unassigned local variable' error when I try to access the variable(s) captured. I tried checking the crashing code also inside VsCode, still getting the error, however if I debug inside Linqpad I can see the variables that are captured got values at least.

```
    var someOddNumbers = new int[] { 1, 3, 5, 7, 9, 11 };
    bool resultX = someOddNumbers is [1, 3, _, _, _, 11];
    resultX.Dump("The 'someOddNumbers' equals a sequence of numbers 1,3,then three arbitrary numbers, then 11?");

    bool isOdd = someOddNumbers is [1, .., 9, 11];
    isOdd.Dump("The 'someOddNumbers' equals a sequence of numbers 1, some arbitrary numbers, then ending with 9 and 11?");
    
    result = input is [var firstOddNumber,.. , var lastOddNumber];

    if (result)
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"The captured variables are: {firstOddNumber} and {lastOddNumber}"); //this lines gives the CS0165 error
    }
```

If I comment out the if block I can run the code sample, and in the debugger I can see firstOddNumber and lastOddNumber being set to a value at runtime. But the C# 11 compiler seems to think this is illeagal code since it is using an unintialized variable.

[image: Captured variables filled with value at runtime]

I expected to not get a compiler error and be able to also capture the variables defined in the list pattern. I cannot understand the usage of such variables if I cannot use them. I understand that these variables might not be captured if the list pattern does not match, but even when checking if a match was present, I got the compilation error. I can however run the code, just not access the variables.

Update:
A comma was missing before lastOddNumber as Guru Stron mentioned from my code. And using the list pattern inside a if condition made the code work.

```
var someOddNumbers = new int[] { 1, 3, 5, 7, 9, 11 };
bool resultX = someOddNumbers is [1, 3, _, _, _, 11];
resultX.Dump("The 'someOddNumbers' equals a sequence of numbers 1,3,then three arbitrary numbers, then 11?");

bool isOdd = someOddNumbers is [1, .., 9, 11];
isOdd.Dump("The 'someOddNumbers' equals a sequence of numbers 1, some arbitrary numbers, then ending with 9 and 11?");

if (someOddNumbers is [var firstOddNumber, .. ,  var lastOddNumber]){   
    Console.WriteLine($"The captured variables are: {firstOddNumber} and {lastOddNumber}");
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that compiler is not smart enough at the moment to determine that `result` is the match result and is not changed (or there are to many edge cases to implement such validation). Inlining the variable should make the code compiling:

```cs
if (input is [var firstOddNumber,.. var lastOddNumber])
{
    Console.WriteLine($"The captured variables are: {firstOddNumber} and {lastOddNumber}"); 
}
```

Small note:

`.. var lastOddNumber` matches the rest of the array, not the last element, probably you were looking for `is [var firstOddNumber, .., var lastOddNumber]` (i.e. add comma after `..`).

**UPD**

The same behaviour can be found with "ordinary" pattern matching:

```cs
string? message = "This is not the null string";

if (message is {} m)
{
    Console.WriteLine(m); // compiles
}

var test = message is {} m1;
if(test)
{
   Console.WriteLine(m1); // error CS0165: Use of unassigned local variable 'm1'
}
```

This actually a known issue that compiler does not propagate the definite assignment state - see [this](https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/issues/16466) and/or [this](https://github.com/dotnet/csharpstandard/issues/290).

[Demo](https://sharplab.io/#v2:C4LgTgrgdgPgAgJgIwFgBQ6BuBDMACASygAcJg8BePKAUwHcBtAXTwG88kAaPBPAXwDc6dAQBmeABRFS5AgGc8DHPlEEwc4AHkAJtoByEALYAjGmG4A6C3mV4ANtg079R02CYBKdK3QBIOEgAnBIAJABEACoAFjR4AMbYxMAQYDTaNrgE2MZ2NAq4NCBsqupaugYmZnx42FDprA5O5a5VYR4CeAD0ncBR8vZEeXgA5gSYQ72xAMIAygAMSABsAKx4ZmAA9mDofMJoAXMA/HiGeXLYw7FUkX0K/VAb5JPUEHZ2eAdhQhhoYpKncnOl0IClY1UMXjQPjQeFhHyCEgh312P1swDy5CoAKBsX6YJOSG+Ygk6I0kOhcO68OChiQ7VhVPWWzwswWKyKAFU5LENuJoI45ARhrR0nYNgl3sosjlYgByWmynZ7IA=).

**UPD**

The issue was closed by [Jon Skeet](https://github.com/dotnet/csharpstandard/issues/290#issuecomment-1577522766) with comment:

> Closing as "unfortunate, but compiler and spec agree."

So for now this will not be implemented.

Comment: Avoiding the use of a boolean flag but using it directly inside a if clause made it compile. 

if (someOddNumbers is [var firstOddNumber, .. ,  var lastOddNumber]){ 
  Console.WriteLine($"The captured variables are: {firstOddNumber} and {lastOddNumber}");
 }